# Way to create circles in specific location in Illustrator or Indesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, automation, illustrator-scripting, anchor-point

I have 167 coordinate points (origin is the left lower corner of a sheet) in which I need to place a circle, the center of it.

Is there any way to create those circles (15 mm diamater) automatically in Illustartor or Indesign to the specific loctions related to the origin?

Or do I need to input all those "coordinates" manually?

Comment: Do you want to make 167 circles?

Comment: Basically yes and all of them in specific location in a sheet, with numbers in each and every one; it will be a complex drill template to use later on after we print it out.

Comment: Do you have anchor points at all of your coordinates already?

Comment: No, at the moment I just have a blanc sheet and I am trying to avoid inputing all those 167 x,y places manually for every circle.

Comment: I do a have an excel sheet with all the locations marked with the correct circle number.

Comment: @Arazzo Why do you need illustrator or indesign at all if your using excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script [`Dup At Selected Anchors.jsx`](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#dup_at) to place a path at every one of your anchor points.

You just place your source shape (circle) in the foreground and it will duplicate it at all of the selected anchor points.

---

To add your anchor points, use a script such as this one to add anchor points at selected coordinates:

```
var piRef = activeDocument.pathItems;
{
    var pathRef = piRef.add();

    pathRef.setEntirePath( new Array(
                new Array(617.943,-723.929),
                new Array(722.168,-640.831),
                new Array(558.789,-530.971),
                new Array(322.168,-252.098) ) ) ;
}
```

Make sure you have only one coordinate per line and then just use find and replace in your favorite text editor (I used Notepad++) and add to the beginning of your line (`^` in regex):

```
new Array(
```

and to the end of the line (`$` in regex)

```
),
```

Then just correct the last line.

---

With this script you will have a huge jungle of lines going everywhere, but the anchor points will be in the correct position, then you can run the script from the beginning of the answer and that will place your circle on every anchor point.

[image: gif]

Comment: Hmm... I must be doing something wrong, since I get:
Error 1220: Illeagal Argument
Line 5:
->    pathRef.setEntirePath( new Array(

Comment: What is the code you used?

Comment: You can email it to me or post a screenshot.

Comment: You have to use `.` not `,` for decimals. Like: `new Array(238.2,458.7),`

Comment: The script assumes that units are PIXELS, so initial work/placement has to be made using pixels as units, then change units what ever you want and scale/transform work to desired size. Other than that, it works exactly like I wanted, thank you, WELZ!